# Google CardDAV API addressbook-multiget returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-api, carddav, google-shared-contacts

I'm trying to retrieve all contacts from Google Contacts via Google's CardDAV API.
According to the [CardDAV Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/carddav/#synchronizing_contacts), this should be done via sending a `addressbook-multiget REPORT`. Which, according to [RFC 6352](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#page-31), should look like this:

> ```
> REPORT https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/foo@gmail.com/lists/default HTTP/1.1
> ```

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.foo-bar
Depth: 1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 204
```

> 

```
<C:addressbook-multiget xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
<D:prop>
<D:getetag />
<C:address-data>
<C:prop name="EMAIL"/>
</C:address-data>
</D:prop>
</C:addressbook-multiget>
```

Unfortunately, I'm constantly getting `(400) Bad Request` for all `REPORT` requests.
I do include Authorization header with OAuth2 access token and Depth header set to 1 in the request and I'm sending it to `https://www.googleapis.com/carddav/v1/principals/foo@gmail.com/lists/default` via HTTPS. And I do have the access to CardDAV API granted in Developer Console.

Have anyone got this working and/or has a clue of what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one step. The multiget report will retrieve contacts, based on a list of resource uris (hrefs). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-8.7.1

To get the list of hrefs in the first place, you can:

- either issue a PROPFIND request with depth 1, targetting the same uri (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.1)
- or issue a WebDAV Sync report (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6578).

WebDAV Sync is the preferred method, especially if you have large collections of contacts.

Comment: Exactly! The appropriate <D:href>/carddav/v1/principals/foo@gmail.com/lists/default/bar</D:href> elements, were what I was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you managed to get *initial* sync (i.e. empty `<DAV:sync-token/>` element) working on Google CardDAV via WebDAV collection sync?

Answer (score 5):

Google CardDav requires a Filter element, but I found that if you don't include a match criteria, all entries will be returned, and doesn't require hrefs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<C:addressbook-query xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
<D:prop>
    <D:getetag />
    <C:address-data />
</D:prop>
<C:filter>
    <C:prop-filter name="FN">
    </C:prop-filter>    
</C:filter>
</C:addressbook-query>
```